# jquery next and find adding css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have following html structure

```
<select id="StatusMultiselect" class="multiselect form-control" name="Status" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;"> </select>
   <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%;">
       <button class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">
        ...
    </div>
```

I'm trying to add class to button element knowing `StatusMultiselect` selector using jquery like this

```
 $('#StatusMultiselect').next().find('.multiselect .dropdown-toggle .btn .btn-default').addClass('gray');
```

but this doesn't work.

Where I'm wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces in the selector are used to find the element i.e. [**descendant selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) which will search for the element having class `b` inside element having class `a` in `.a .b`.

```
.find('.multiselect.dropdown-toggle.btn.btn-default') // Remove spaces in the selector
    .addClass('gray');
```

If no space is used in the classes in the selector the element having all the classes is selected.

```js
$('#StatusMultiselect').next().find('.multiselect.dropdown-toggle.btn.btn-default').addClass('gray');
```

```css
.gray {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="StatusMultiselect" class="multiselect form-control" name="Status" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;"></select>
<div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%;">
  <button class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, but I still struggling, in firebug gray class is not added. Can you please double check that my next() and find operations are correct?

Comment: @user1765862 For the given code this is correct, check the demo. If this doesn't work for you, please create jsfiddle demo with complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces between classnames. Otherwise it will search for the child elements.

```
$('#StatusMultiselect').next().find('.multiselect.dropdown-toggle.btn.btn-default').addClass('gray')
```